# Iterate completely through a Java array before doing else part of condition

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

So the problem I'm running into is I want to test each part of an array against a condition, and if ALL the parts of the array return false I want to do something but if any of them return true I want to do something else. For example

```
  String[] arr = new String[8];
  for(String s : arr) {
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("example") {
      // Do this
    } else {
      // do that
    }
  }
```

The problem with the above is that is will do this or do that for all 8 pieces of the array. What I want is for it to test all of them, and if they're all false do that but if any of them are true then do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous answer has the conditions backwards. It was testing if ANY is FALSE, "Do this" and if ALL are TRUE "Do that". Try this code:

```
String[] arr = new String[8];
boolean found = false;
for(String s : arr) {
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("example")) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(found) {
    // Do this
} else {
    // Do that
}
```

Comment: I literally just finished editing the other answer to reflect the conditions the correct way :P thanks

Comment: That's because my edit needs to be peer reviewed... I'll mark this one as correct since it's correct without edits needed.

Answer (score 5):

```
String[] arr = new String[8];
boolean isAllGood = true;
for(String s : arr) {
    if(!s.equalsIgnoreCase("example") {
        isAllGood = false;
        break;  
    } 
}

if(isAllGood) {
    //do this
} else {
    //do that
}
```

Comment: This example has the conditions backwards and won't work the way that is desired.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the loop to another function say isSomeCondition( String[] someArr )